# Grouping in MongoDB Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am starting with MongoDB and i find the Aggregate function hard to understand.

i have read many topics and tried many things, however i still don't get the results i am looking for.

I would like to group some things together to make a overview of the amount of things based on a few match parameters.

my DB:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5943a4f015813165b6d2b79a"),
"productType" : "mail",
"productAmount" : 1,
"orderid" : "1497607274",
"location" : "99",
"sublocation" : "02",
"date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T09:01:13.000Z"),
"__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5943a4f915813165b6d2b79c"),
    "productType" : "mail",
    "productAmount" : 1,
    "orderid" : "1497607274",
    "location" : "99",
    "sublocation" : "01",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T09:01:13.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5943a4fe15813165b6d2b79e"),
    "productType" : "mail",
    "productAmount" : 1,
    "orderid" : "1497607274",
    "location" : "25",
    "sublocation" : "01",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T09:01:13.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5943a56d15813165b6d2b7a0"),
    "productType" : "mail",
    "productAmount" : 1,
    "orderid" : "1497607274",
    "location" : "99",
    "sublocation" : "01",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T09:01:13.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5943a971a367b069bb3e863c"),
    "productType" : "mail",
    "productAmount" : 1,
    "orderid" : "1497607274",
    "location" : "98",
    "sublocation" : "01",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T09:01:13.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5943d824900fce1821c5845d"),
    "productType" : "keychain",
    "productAmount" : 1,
    "orderid" : "1497607251",
    "location" : "25",
    "sublocation" : "01",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T09:01:13.000Z")
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5943d9ea900fce1821c5845e"),
    "productType" : "mail",
    "productAmount" : 1,
    "orderid" : "1497607251",
    "location" : "25",
    "sublocation" : "02",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T09:01:13.000Z")
}
```

my current query:

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
{ $group: { 
    _id : {
        "orderid" : "$orderid",
        "location" : "$location",
        "product" : "$productType",
        "sublocation" : "$sublocation",
        "date" : "$date",
        "aant" : { "$sum" : "$productAmount"}
    },
    "aantal" : { "$sum" : 1},
    "aantal2" : { "$sum" : "$productAmount"}
   }
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id.product", 
        "productType" : {
            "$push" : {
                "loc" : "$_id.location",
                "prodtype": "$_id.product",
                "count": "$aantal2"},
            },
            "cnt": {"$sum" : "$aantal2"}
        }
    }
])
```

i would like to have this result:

```
{
     Location: 25,
     sublocation: 01,
     <productTypeX> : <count the number of these products>,
     <productTypeY> : <count the number of these products>,
     <productTypeZ> : <count the number of these products>
},
{
     Location: 25,
     sublocation: 02,
     <productTypeX> : <count the number of these products>,
     <productTypeY> : <count the number of these products>,
     <productTypeZ> : <count the number of these products>
}
```

or:

```
{
    location: 25,
    sublocation: 01,
    products: [
         {
              <productTypeX> : <count>,
              <productTypeY> : <count>,
              <productTypeZ> : <count>
         }
},
{ 
    location: 25,
    sublocation: 02
    products: [
         {
              <productTypeX> : <count>,
              <productTypeY> : <count>,
              <productTypeZ> : <count>
         }
 }
```

if i get this to work i need to convert it to mongoose for NodeJS (tips are welcome)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do mean convert? It's exactly the same syntax.

Comment: oke, the nodejs variant for mongoose query is the same as for the shell where i am testing now?

Comment: Also [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) is an "accumulator" which in the `$group` context means it needs to be "outside" of `_id`, which is the grouping key. beyond that, you are not far off getting a result. I suggest you try a bit harder, as it's how you are going to learn.

Comment: i am already trying very hard. i know i am getting there, but i am stuck, if i get a push in the right direction it would make a great difference :)

Comment: 100% The same. It's all JavaScript, and it really does not differ that much in "most" language implementations. For instance Python and Ruby are also "mostly" identical. The node difference will be "callbacks" but that's a different story.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info, but i still need the correct aggregate query..

Comment: I really think it would be more beneficial if you read the documentation link I gave you, understood it, and then attempted to correct yourself. We don't mind helping with problems, but basic syntax should be something you pick up before asking a question here.